# Modulo de Login com Spring Security

Tags: aplicação-web, spring, login, spring-security

Galera, estou estudando o Spring Framework e todos os outros *frameworks* que ele disponibiliza e gostaria muito de implementar um modulo de *login*.

Atualmente estou usando Spring sem nenhum uso de XML exceto o `pom.xml`, e muitos dos sites que acessei tinham exemplos em XML.

1. Há muita diferença entre Spring Security implementado com XML ou JAVA?
2. Algum deles tem alguma vantagem ou desvantagem? Pelo  que vi o XML acaba ficando muito extenso e difícil de manter com o tempo.
3. Vocês teriam algum tutorial para iniciantes que trabalhasse com códigos java?

Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 1):

1. Há muita diferença entre Spring Security implementado com XML ou JAVA?

  Você consegue criar um projeto tanto com o XML bem como utilizando o Java.

2. Algum deles tem alguma vantagem ou desvantagem? Pelo que vi o XML acaba ficando muito extenso e difícil de manter com o tempo.

  Uma vantagem da Configuração em Java, é que ele acusa erro de sintaxe, Já na configuração em XML, você só vai descobrir o erro ao executar o projeto.

3. Vocês teriam algum tutorial para iniciantes que trabalhasse com códigos java?

  Eu recomendo dá uma pesquisada em alguns repositórios do github ou do bitbucket, segue um link de um projeto meu da faculdade:
  [Exemplo](https://bitbucket.org/joaops_20/stockcar)
  (Para executar a applicação, você precisa ter o banco de dados postgreSQL instalado além de criar uma base de dados com o nome de "stockcar")
  Tente também, procurar algum tutorial em inglês, sempre tem mais conteúdo para estudar.